# Reversi game color detection

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

I am recreating the classic game Reversi using c# in order to improve my skills at programming
but I have a problem when I check the colors. So far I have managed to revers colors from left and from top but it doesn't work correctly it only reverses the colors when I hit the last square on the board.

Any help would be much appreciated

Here is an image that may explain what I mean (the code is below)[image] mean

The code that I have:

```
namespace praprevers
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button[,] squares;
        //private Button[,] r0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            squares = new Button[4, 4];
            squares = new Button[,] {
                                    {btn_0_0, btn_0_1, btn_0_2, btn_0_3},
                                    {btn_1_0, btn_1_1, btn_1_2, btn_1_3},
                                    {btn_2_0, btn_2_1, btn_2_2, btn_2_3},
                                    {btn_3_0, btn_3_1, btn_3_2, btn_3_3}
                                    };

        }

        int _turn = 0;
        private void DrawColor(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           Button b = sender as Button;
            string[] btnData = b.Name.Split('_');
            int x = int.Parse(btnData[1]);
            int y = int.Parse(btnData[2]);

            //check for possible combinations 
            int top = x - 3;
            int botton = x +3;

            int left = y - 3;
            int right = y + 3;

           for (int l = 0; l < 4; ++l)
            {
                if (top >= 0 && squares[top, y].BackColor == Color.Black)
                {
                    squares[top + l, y].BackColor = Color.Black;

                }
                else if (left >= 0 && squares[x, left].BackColor == Color.Black)
                {
                    squares[x, left + l].BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
           }
            if (_turn == 0)
            {
                _turn = 1;
                b.BackColor = Color.Black;


            }
            else
            {
                _turn = 0;
                b.BackColor = Color.Red;


            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Button sqrr in squares)
            {
                sqrr.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DrawColor);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: At a glance, one problem may be that your logic for changing the colors of buttons happens *before* you color the clicked button.

Comment: Ok that's another problem but my initial problem is reversing the colors properly

Comment: They are related problems, since your logic for changing the colors of the buttons seemingly relies on the what button was just pressed being the correct color as well.

Comment: Ok I am trying to fix this